# How to set Imagery Offset in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, openstreetmap, mapbox-gl-js

is it possible to use leaflet to move tile layer based on a offset

The problem is that I use OSM data to display markers and building outlines on the map but since am using another Tile Provider the OSM data is not sync with satellite image

Is there a simple way of adding offset in leaflet?

attached a screenshoot from openstreetmap's iD editor :

https://youtu.be/IRLyMKVERvo

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to use leaflet to move tile layer based on a offset?

[Yes](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html).

> Is there a simple way of adding offset in leaflet?

[No](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html).

---

There are several approaches to offsetting a Leaflet `L.TileLayer`, but they're not straight forward. I would advise reading about [extending Leaflet classes](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html) and reading Leaflet's source code before undertaking such a task.

One approach would be to use a [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) on the specific bit of code that calculates the CSS offset of tiles, i.e. [the internal `_getTilePos()` method of `L.GridLayer`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/ec35ab52f66c191f7c855583354722c40dcdf239/src/layer/tile/GridLayer.js#L894):

```
_getTilePos: function (coords) {
    return coords.scaleBy(this.getTileSize()).subtract(this._level.origin);
},
```

That internal method takes in the *tile* coordinates, and returns the *pixel* coordinates relative to what Leaflet calls the *origin pixel*. Those concepts are [documented](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html).

So I can create a decorator by subclassing `L.TileLayer` and creating a new class with a new implementation for `_getTilePos` (but reusing the implementation of the parent class), e.g.

```
var OffsetTileLayer = L.TileLayer.extend({
    _getTilePos: function (coords) {
        var pos = L.TileLayer.prototype._getTilePos.call(this, coords);
        return pos.add([25, 25]);
    },
});

var offsetTileLayer = new OffsetTileLayer(/* etc */);
offsetTileLayer.addTo(map);
```

See a [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/H5phWJCjQY43Qj6l).

That will offset the CSS position of tiles (which is represented by an instance of `L.Point`) by 25 horizontal and vertical pixels. Note that the offset is CSS pixels; *not* meters and *not* degrees of latitude/longitude.

It would be possible to make that offset depend on the tile coordinates (from which the latitude, longitude and scale can be derived), but I suspect that there would be artefacts (such as gaps between tiles) if the geodetic calculations involved (i.e. how to calculate meters from the tile coords) are not done with care.

Comment: I think `Is there a simple way of ...?` is a great question and simply an alternative way of asking `How do you ...?` as it implies a `If so, how?`. It is polite and immediately clear to anyone reading (except robots, maybe).